# Non-overlaping Domain decomposition - assemble of Laplacian

Tags: pde, finite-difference, preconditioning, domain-decomposition

I am dealing with following 2-dimensional problem in the unit square domain $S_2$

$$- \Delta u (x,y) = f \  \text{in} \ S_2,  \hspace{1.5cm} u(x,y) = 0 \ \text{on} \  \partial S_2$$

where $f$ is such the analytical solution to problem is

$$u(x,y) = \cos [  2 \pi x  (y - x) ]^2.$$

Problem should be discretized by 5-point finite difference scheme, which will result in Ax = b system. 
I need to decompose problem into 4 non-overlaping domains. Should I divide  my domain square into 4 parts and then assemble? or assemble and then divide? Main question here is, how the laplacians will look like.

Comment: Why do you have to decompose the problem into 4 non-overlapping domains? Is that part of the problem description somehow?

Comment: @HH No it is my choice. It can be as many domains as I want, but they have to be non-overlaping. I have chosen 4, since it is a 2D square it is easy to  do cut in middle of every dimension.